# Flash develop "this file has no associated application..."

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, openfl

I find myself trying to learn how to develop in haxe as well as openfl and I am using flash develop as my IDE.

However whenever I create a project (which work perfectly fine) and then try to debug it, I get the error

"This file has no associated application that can preform the action"

And though I know the solution is probably really simple I just don't see it (I am a newbie)

I wish i had more information to give but im not sure what is relevant...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you targeting flash? Is the flash player installed (and associated with .swf)?

Comment: Yes I am targeting flash(thought it would be a good place to start) and I am pretty certain flash player is installed. But I don't know if it is associated with .swf

Comment: Try Tools -> Install Software -> Flash Player (SA) in FlashDevelop and tell windows to use that to open .swf files.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it was a combination of that and using an older version of flash player, and like I said it was something way to simple :)